# Loop animation with velocity.js

Tags: javascript, android, ios, velocity.js

I'm trying to do that kind of loop animation with velocity.js: translate object on X axis from 0 to 473, then from 0 to 473 and so on.

I've succeeded to do that like this (code below) but on Android Chrome and iOS Chrome browsers the loop starts over with some delay (lag). Can someone help?

```
function start() {
  $(".el").velocity(
    { 
      translateX: [ -473, 0 ]
    },
    { 
      duration: 8000,
      delay: 0,
      easing: "linear",
      complete: reset
    });
}
function reset() {
    $(".el").css("transform", "translate(0px, 0px)");
    start();
}
start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using forcefeeding, the `.css()` call is redundant.

Removing that line removes the initial lag on Chrome for Android:

```
$el = $(".el");
function start() {
  $el.velocity(
    { 
      translateX: [ -473, 0 ]
    },
    { 
      duration: 8000,
      delay: 0,
      easing: "linear",
      complete: start
    });
}

start();
```

And you can see a live version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3eeLo819/4/).

Comment: Thank you for answering. Indeed `.css()` call is not necessary. However the lag still presists on Chrome iOS and Safari iOS. Haven't tested Android yet. Updated the live version with animation that represents the lag: http://jsfiddle.net/3eeLo819/6/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work on Android Chrome, you need to remove the `float` and set `display: inline-block`, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3eeLo819/7/). This works great on Android

Comment: One more question, can same animation be done without using "forcefeeding" technique?

Comment: Currently no, it's also mentioned in the docs. But I know Julian is working on implementing a support for this, or at least is planning to. There should be another release before 2015 that may contain that feature.

Comment: Not sure whether you have the same problem in your case. I've updated the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3eeLo819/15/ by removing the scroll change and hiding overflow of the content from the webview, I think this should solve your issues on iOS.

Comment: Is there a better way of doing this then via recursion? Would love to have a possibility of setting `loop: true` and maybe `resetOnLoop: true` or something similar.

Comment: @Markus  Have the same problem. Is there any update on this? Recursion is unfortunately to laggy in my tests :(

Answer (score 0):

Writing an answer if someone looks here again.
There's now an option in [**Velocity 1.2.0**](http://velocityjs.org/#loop) to loop by setting `loop: true` or to an integer to loop a number of times, e.g.

```
$el = $(".el");
function start() {
  $el.velocity(
    { 
      translateX: [ -473, 0 ]
    },
    { 
      duration: 8000,
      delay: 0,
      easing: "linear",
      loop: true
    });
}

start();
```